# redirect all URLS to no trailing slash php

Tags: .htaccess, trailing-slash

My folder structure is, I used htaccess for NO trailing slash at the end of each URL

```
-job.php to /job
-companies.php to /companies
-about.php to /about
-Admin_jobs(This is Admin Folder)
```

and My .htaccess file is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com [NC]
#redirect to www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

.
I am trying to access my Admin_jobs/ folder then it was redirecting to my main site, www.example.com. I cannot access to My admin pages. Anybody is there to help me.

Comment: There is nothing in your rules to redirect `Admin_jobs` to `www.example.com`.

Comment: I don,t want redirect. I need to access that folder. While I am typing www.example.com/Admin_jobs it was taking me to www.example.com